# Responsibility of constructor, how much may it does?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I want know if a constructor can do "deeped" things, of just initializing. Consider this:

```
class Entity
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $datasAlready)
    {
        $this->json_encode($datasAlready);
    }
}
```

exising a `Entity` is pointless if no `$data` was filled. This way, I enforce load this.
But my boss told its not okay, constructor ideally would only do basic inicializations, so:

```
class Entity
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $datasAlready)
    {
        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function load(array $datasAlready)
    {
        $this->json_encode($datasAlready);
    }
}
```

or even constructor is not needed. But this way I miss the enforcing of initialization. What if I start using this object when not filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor almost like normal function and you can do anything inside it.
But it's not best practics.

If you don't describe constructor in class, will be used default empty constructor.